# Why Serial number getting skipped while using Having clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My Query :

```
    Select 
        @a:=@a+1 serial_number,
        CONCAT_WS(' ',ap.FirstName,ap.LastName) as Name,
        Count(t.ID) as NoOfBookings
    from 
        tablereservation t, 
        appusers ap , 
        (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a 
    where 
        t.AppUserID = ap.ID 
        AND
        t.RestaurantID = p_RestaurantID 
    GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(' ',ap.FirstName,ap.LastName) 
    HAVING Count(t.ID)=1
    Order by serial_number;
```

Result :

[image]

I want Serial Number starts from 1 to 4 but it is starting from 5.

TableReservation Table :

[image]

User Table :

[image]

Comment: provide some sample data from both the tables.

Comment: Hey abhik i have added tables